# Best way to script / persist a standard Firefox configuration for Windows 10 Sandbox?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, windows-sandbox

I don't know if this is a Windows 10 question or a Firefox scripting question. Probably the latter because I can't find anything on how to customize the sandbox.

I'd like to automate applying certain changes to the Windows 10 sandbox when it starts up - install Firefox, add an extension to it, and change a few configuration settings.

Or even better, update the state of the "pristine" Windows 10 sandbox image so scripting isn't necessary.

Is there an easy way to do either of those things?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run script that require admin-right, you script will not run.
You can do it but putting you script in startup folder
eg:

```
<MappedFolder>
 <HostFolder>C:\Your Path to Script Folder</HostFolder>
 <SandboxFolder>C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup</SandboxFolder>
 <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>
</MappedFolder>
```

Hope this help.